# Reloading Views based on Tab Bar Interaction Xcode 7 Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I am tying to design a view controller that calls a method to load the embedded mail app on the iOS device as soon as the user taps the icon for that view, and every time it's tapped.

But after the mail client is either "Canceled", "Saved", "Sent" etc. The next time the user hits the Tab bar icon for that view controller the view is just a blank screen, it doesn't attempt to load the view again. I tried implementing a function call to loadView() or loadWillAppear() again but it ended up with an infinite loop where every time the mail client ended the client would load again instantly.

Perhaps I included the call a little early? I tried to even include some if statements to catch the program while it's running but it didn't seem to do anything at all. There's a couple places in here where I know it would be an infinite loop or what have you I just can't seem to get it to work. I was also unable to use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
```

Because the compiler complains about it and parsing boolean values is "Bad".

Anyways, here is the code from my ContactViewControllerTwo.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ContactViewControllerTwo: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

var mailControllerDidLoad = false
var mailControllerDismissed = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    viewWillAppear()
}

func viewWillAppear() {

    if mailControllerDidLoad == false {


        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

            let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
            composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
            composeVC.setToRecipients(["123@123.com"])
            presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        else if mailControllerDidLoad == true && mailControllerDismissed == false{

            let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
            composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
            composeVC.setToRecipients(["123@123.com"])
            presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {
            print("Cannot send mail - Please try again")
            // give feedback to the user

        }
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if self.isMovingFromParentViewController()
    {
        print("View controller")
    }
    else
    {
        print("New view controller.")
        viewWillAppear()
        print("Loaded again")

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
        didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    mailControllerDidLoad = true

    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
        print("Cancelled")
        mailControllerDismissed = true
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
        print("Saved")
        mailControllerDismissed = true
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        print("Sent")
        mailControllerDismissed = true
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
        print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        mailControllerDismissed = true
    default:
        mailControllerDismissed = true
        break

    }
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    mailControllerDismissed = true

}
}
```